# Search in XML/HTML/JSP in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, plugins

I need to look for a jsp element with/without specific attribute in > 100 jsp files and I was wondering if there is a plugin/search option in Eclipse for that?

Thank you,
al

Comment: So the `File Search` is not suitable for you?

Comment: File Search would work, yes (regexes and so). But I was looking for some solution specific to XML, like XPath search or similar.

Comment: File Search is working fine, but we are searching through CTRL + Shift + T their cann' t be searched.

Answer (score 0):

Try Navigate > go to > resource

Comment: If I understand correctly, go to -> resource allows me to jump to a specific file and I need to look in the files for a tag.